# Create Common Shared Pages Working With Next JS and Turborepo

Tags: next.js, routes, monorepo, turborepo

I have a `monorepo` created with turborepo which contains two `next.js` apps. The structures is as follows

```
base
|---apps
|   |---editor
|   |    |---pages
|   |        |---index.js //this file is different in both apps
|   |        |---anotherPage.js //this is the same file in both apps
|   |   
|   |---etsy
|        |---pages
|            |---index.js //this file is different in both apps
|            |---anotherPage.js //this is the same file in both apps
|
|---package
```

In Next JS, there is automatic routing. So when I go to `url/otherPage`, it is automatically redirected to the `otherPage.js` page. I have a bunch of common pages between the apps. And a bunch of common APIs in the `pages/api` directory. How can I make a system where those shared pages are kept under the `packages` directory while still keeping the automatic routing and api routing.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for that? I'm mostly interesting in sharing api's between apps!